# Remixd local host instance not Working!

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to run remixd in the terminal, and it first initially looks for open ports and I am able to connect to my local host, but after a few moments it shuts down because of some restrictions on denied access to the Trash section of my mac. WHAT should i do

Comment: can you share the terminal output/logs for more context?